# Normal Operation Current for ESD Diode

Tags: diodes, esd

I want to use a ESD Diode against Vehicle Battery which is rated @ 36V max. I have selected below Diode :-

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PESD36VS1UL.pdf

Now, I am okay with working voltage which is 36V & peak pulse current which is 2.5A. But I could not find any information on continuous current rating. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Maybe you want to explain what you want to do with that diode that you need such a rating

Comment: @PlasmaHH - I have my circuit connected to Vehicle Battery of 36V. There are few digital & Analog signals coming from various sensors of Vehicle. I want to protect my 36V power input line & other 36 V signals from ESD. I will take almost 1A continuous current from Vehicle battery @ 36V.

Comment: You really need to add a circuit and show us your protection scheme. The right component in the wrong circuit can offer worse protection than the wrong component in the right circuit.

Answer (score 1):

To protect your installation, the ESD diode will be in parallel to the protected circuit. As far as I can tell, the current used by the circuit is not relevant for the choice of your ESD diode.

There will be a bit of leakage current that is the stats in page 3 of the datasheet : "IRM reverse leakage current". Since this is a protection diode, in normal behavior it will not let flow current through itself. If there is a problem and the voltage rise, at this moment the diode will conduct in order to protect the circuit.